# MySQL vs Readdir PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I got a directory with lots of files. Over 10.000 files. We are going to refactor this directory. Each 2 files belong to a certain "item". Our plan is now to split the directory in multiple directories and give each "item" it's own directory with each own files.

At the moment, we store the filenames in our database together with the primary key of an "item".

Now I was wondering, what is the best solution to manage these files? Is it better to use php's readdir function to read the directory to get the images or is it better to read the database table and get the files with those names?

I am wondering what gives the best performance and what is the most common way to deal with lots of images.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Go through the database. Assuming it is properly indexed, it will be orders of magnitude faster than scanning the filesystem for the folders you want.

Find the records you're interested in via an SQL query, and then locate the corresponding files on disk. This is not only faster, but serves as a foundation for more additional features: You'll be able search and sort records much more easily than implementing similar features yourself on top of a linear search of the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

i'd use the database to lookup files. readdir can be slow and it can't be done with the same amount of intelligence a an sql query. also if you decide to move the dir s3 then you are limited by the choice of using readdir. also using readdir forces the files to be on the same server as the php client hwich is also another limitation.